# Can you give an example of stack overflow in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, g++, stack-overflow

Can you give an example of stack overflow in C++?

Comment: You want me to implement the whole stackoverflow website in C++ in my answer? Wow... :)

Comment: Why isn't infinite recursion an acceptable answer?

Comment: Why isn't a trivial case an acceptable answer?

Comment: The above won’t overflow on a decent compiler. No stack, no operation, no nothing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The typical case that does not involve infinite recursion is declaring an automatic variable on the stack that is too large. For example:

```
int foo()
{
    int array[1000000];

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Please see [Stack overflow - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#C.2FC.2B.2B.2FObjective-C.2FObjective-C.2B.2B_examples).  I have linked directly to the examples section.

Answer (score 8):

```
void function() 
{
    function();
}
```

Comment: +1 clean and straightforward. This is ALL you need to blow the stack.

Comment: Can we make it shorter? Yes, we can! `void _(){_();}` ... it's almost like Perl ;)

Comment: The difference is, in Perl land, it's more likely that you'll blow *your* stack before Perl does.

Comment: Since this function takes no arguments, declares nothing, and returns nothing, I wonder if a smart optimizer might simple turn this into an infinite loop, in which case, it would not blow the stack...

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that might happen in practice:

```
int factorial(int x) {
  return x == 0 ? 1 : x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

This overflows the stack for negative `x`. And, [as Frank Krueger mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657484/can-you-give-an-example-of-stack-overflow-in-c/1657520#1657520), also for too large `x` (but then `int` would overflow first).

Answer (score 3):

Keep trying to return main until the stack runs out?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: It's not legal to call main() in C++.

Comment: I know it won't format correctly, but there's no warnings with `-Wall` even for this more proper program: <code>int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 0){return 0;}
    else {std::cout << argc << std::endl; return main(0, argv);}
}
</code>

Comment: I mean it's odd that `g++` doesn't give any warnings when you call main; you are indeed correct (from what I've seen) that the standard disallows calling `main`.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: g++ does give an error if you compile with the `-pedantic` flag, although in my case it gives the somewhat incorrect error of `ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main'`

Answer (score 3):

As per edit :-)

```
void ping()
{
    pong();
}

void pong()
{
    ping();
}
```

Also, I believe you can get stack overflow if you try to allocate more space than maximum thread stack size ( 1MB by default in VS), so something like `int a[100000];` should provide the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Compile-time example:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

// ...
{
    int overflow = Factorial<10>::value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe we left off the greatest recursion example of all time, factorial!

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fact(double n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 1;
    else return n * fact(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    printf("fact(5) = %g\n", fact(5));
    printf("fact(10) = %g\n", fact(10));
    printf("fact(100) = %g\n", fact(100));
    printf("fact(1000) = %g\n", fact(1000));
    printf("fact(1000000) = %g\n", fact(1000000));
}
```

On OS X 10.5.8 with GCC 4.0.1:

```
$ gcc f.c -o f && ./f
fact(5) = 120
fact(10) = 3.6288e+06
fact(100) = 9.33262e+157
fact(1000) = inf
Segmentation fault
```

Unfortunately, OS X reports a "Segmentation fault" instead of a "Stack overflow". Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows uncontrolled recursion. Eventually, the stack spaced allocated to this process will be completely overwritten by instances of bar and ret...

```
int foo( int bar )
{
    int ret = foo( 42 );
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *generate* an explicitly non-recursive program to result in a stack overflow by function calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

print "void func" + sys.argv[1] + "() { }"
for i in xrange(int(sys.argv[1])-1, -1, -1):
    print "void func" + str(i) + "() { func" + str(i+1) + "(); }"
print "int main() { func0(); return 0; }"
```

Sample output:

```
$ python recursion.py 5
void func5() { }
void func4() { func5(); }
void func3() { func4(); }
void func2() { func3(); }
void func1() { func2(); }
void func0() { func1(); }
int main() { func0(); return 0; }
```

Sample usage:

```
$ python recursion.py 250000 | g++ -x c++ - && ./a.out
```

At least on my system, the call stack seems to be 174602, so you'll need to set the argument to `recursion.py` to be larger than that; and it takes a few minutes to compile and link the program.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite recursion:

```
void infiniteFunction()
{
    infiniteFunction();
}

int main()
{
    infiniteFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get a stack overflow if you try to put large objects on the stack (by-value).