# How can I get a stack overflow in C++ and Unix?

Tags: c++, unix

I'm wondering how to get an stack overflow error with a simple example, such as:

```
int recursSum (int n)
{
   return (n==1)? 1:n+recursSum(n-1);
}
```

I ask that stupid question because I only have some *Segmentation fault*, even with an empty function calling itself…

Am I missing something or is there any *protection* or something that prevents me for doing this?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657484/can-you-give-an-example-of-stack-overflow-in-c

Comment: In this case, a _stack overflow_ would be the underlying reason why you get the OS-defined _Segmentation fault_ error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A segmentation fault means that the memory protection kicked in and prevented you from accessing memory you did not have available.  This can occur for a [variety of reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Common_causes), but one reason indicated is stack overflow (overflowing the stack into some other segment of memory).

Answer (score 3):

If the function is called with a negative or 0 integer argument, you'll face infinite recursion. However, the compiler likely can tail call optimize that particular function and you'd never see a stack overflow except in debug mode. The segmentation fault lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, a smart compiler might optimize it into an infinite loop. However if it does not (because the OP didn't pass the appropriate -O flag for example), the given code will cause a stack overflow when called with a negative or zero argument, which will cause a segmentation fault (and so will the empty function calling itself that the OP also tried). So I don't see why you think the segmentation fault must lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

A stack overflow is a type of segmentation fault, it looks like your system has just output a generic error.

You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo()

{

    float f[1024];

    Foo();

}
```

f is a dummy variable which will help filling stack quickly.

Comment: You may want to use it somehow, otherwise the optimizer may remove that array completely.

Comment: In this kind of function (and the original question), there's a reasonable chance the compiler will eliminate the recursion, depending on optimization levels, etc.